# Could a manuscript be under review even if the AE was not assigned?

Tags: peer-review, journals, ieee, journal-workflow

There are three things written on the journal’s home page: EIC (editor-in-chief), AE (associate editor) and ADM (administrator). The EIC is assigned, whereas the AE and ADM are not. The status is "Under review". In this situation, what can I expect? Has the EIC invited the reviewers or it is not under review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to disagree with @Allure.  I have been an EIC, and I'm an associate editor of several IEEE and ACM journals.  The manuscript was submitted only 3 weeks ago.  It is possible that the EIC just hasn't gotten to it yet, or is having trouble finding the right associate editor to handle it.  I think the system will say "under review" as long as it has been submitted and not yet accepted or rejected.

It is possible that the EIC is trying to decide *whether* to assign the paper or reject it immediately, but I think that's not the conclusion I'd jump to.

OP should simply be patient.

Comment: We might be using different editorial management systems then - the system I'm most familiar with has statuses "submitted to journal", "editor assigned", and then only "under review". In other words, it doesn't say "under review" unless a reviewer has been invited.

Comment: Could be.... hard to say in isolation....

Answer (score 2):

If it says "under review", it's under review.

My guess is that the EiC decided to handle the paper himself / herself, hence nobody else was assigned.